# Chaining then() and accessing data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

Hi all I'm learning javascript for some few months now and trying to write my first, not trivial app and came across this problem. this is sample of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let contributorsArr = [];
  let url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular';
  let usersArr = [];
  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    let auth = '';
    contributorsArr = data.map(item => {
      let contributions = item.contributions;
      let id = item.id;
      return {id, contributions};
    });


    const userUrls = data.map(item => item.url + auth);
    const users = userUrls.map(userUrl => fetch(userUrl));
    return Promise.all(users);

  }).then(responses => {
    return Promise.all(responses.map(user => user.json()));
  }).then(users => {
    contributorsArr.forEach(function(obj1) {
      users.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (obj1.id === obj.id) {
          Object.assign(obj, obj1);
        }
      });
      return users;
    });

    usersArr.push(users);

    $.each(users, function (index,user) {
      let that = this;

      $('#users').on('click','#userPanel',function (user) {
        console.log(that.id);
      });

      $('#users').append(`
        <div id="userPanel" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">${user.name ? user.name :    user.login}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <img class="thumbnail avatar" src="${user.avatar_url}" alt="avatar">
        <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="${user.html_url}">View Profile on GitHub</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="label label-default">Public Repos: ${user.public_repos} </span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Public Gists: ${user.public_gists}</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Contributions: ${user.contributions}</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Followers: ${user.followers}</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        `);

    });
  });
});
```

My questions are  how do I bind event handlers for each userPanel , and is there a way to sort them  by amount of contributions or gists?

Comment: It would be nice if you could format your code correctly before posting, and if possible, strip out unneeded parts (consider creating a [mcve]). At least I, for one, won't bother with it in its present form.

Comment: I will try better next time thx John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the W3C standard,ID should not be duplicate.

So,use `class="userPanel"` instead of `id="userPanel"`

```
$('#users').on('click','.userPanel',function (user) {
                console.log(this); //using this u can traversee= up-down
            });//move it to outside of each.
```

Actual DOM appending

```
$.each(users,function (index,user) {
            let that = this;

            $('#users').append(`
                    <div class="userPanel" class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">${user.name ? user.name :    user.login}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 ">
                                <img class="thumbnail avatar" src="${user.avatar_url}" alt="avatar">
                                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="${user.html_url}">View Profile on GitHub</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-9">
                            <span class="label label-default">Public Repos: ${user.public_repos} </span>
                            <span class="label label-primary">Public Gists: ${user.public_gists}</span>
                            <span class="label label-success">Contributions: ${user.contributions}</span>
                            <span class="label label-info">Followers: ${user.followers}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>          
                            `);

        });
```